# MySql query to delete duplicate rows by keeping latest timestamp value?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, sql-delete

I am facing a problem regarding the mysql table update. I have table that contains 5 columns including ID, NAME, TIMESTAMP and other 2 columns. My problem is I want to delete those rows whose both ID and NAME matches with another row,s ID and NAME with keeping the latest TIMESTAMP row.

I am trying the following query but it's showing the error:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'dummy1' for update in FROM clause

The query is:

```
delete from dummy1  where LAST_USED_DATE not in(
select max(LAST_USED_DATE) from dummy1
group by ID,NAME);
```

Comment: +1 But please use sql fiddle before asking any question on sql query.

Comment: you want to do it in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```sql
DELETE d
  FROM dummy1 d JOIN 
(
  SELECT d1.id, d1.name, MAX(d1.last_used_date) max_date
    FROM dummy1 d1 JOIN dummy1 d2
      ON d1.id = d2.id AND d1.name = d2.name
   GROUP BY id, name
) q ON d.id = q.id AND d.name = q.name AND d.last_used_date <> q.max_date
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40720/2)** demo

**UPDATE** To check only for duplicate ids you can tweak the above query a bit

```sql
DELETE d
  FROM dummy1 d JOIN 
(
  SELECT d1.id, MAX(d1.last_used_date) max_date
    FROM dummy1 d1 JOIN dummy1 d2
      ON d1.id = d2.id
   GROUP BY id
) q ON d.id = q.id AND d.last_used_date <> q.max_date
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/661de/1)** demo

**UPDATE2** To delete dupes with max timestamp

1) you can by introducing a unique index with `IGNORE` option. In that case MySql will decide itself which records stay.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dummy1 ENGINE MyISAM;
ALTER IGNORE TABLE dummy1 ADD UNIQUE (id, name);
ALTER TABLE dummy1 ENGINE InnoDB;
```

Comment: Can you help me to write another query but I want to check only ID value instead of both ID and NAME field(same condition to keep the latest TIMESTAMP rows)

Comment: @peterm +1 Your query is well understood but it seems a bit difficult to visualize such queries. Is there any such tool to see a graphical view of sql query ?

Comment: @KalpataruMallick See updated answer for a query that check only for duplicate ids.

Comment: @Vivek Unfortunately I don't know any of such tools.

Comment: @peterm There is a another problem that if there is more than one row having max timestamp value then the query keeping all the rows but I want to keep only one rows from those duplicate rows. Please help

Comment: @KalpataruMallick To help you with that I need to have more information about your table. Is there any primary key on the table? If no then is it a possibility for you to introduce one? Can you post the result of `DESC dummy1` and sample data with all columns when id, name and timestamp match?

Comment: @peterm There is no primary key, Its not possible to set primary key because it needs to insert the duplicate data from a .tsv file at first then delete the duplicate rows respective to those 3 columns if you set p.key then then it will show the error if any .tsv file contains the duplicate rows. I cant post the result of sorted data because its too large(>10K). one sample I can provide you where it matches after running your query

Comment: @KalpataruMallick Please post what you can and we'll go from there. Also post the result of `DESC dummy1`.

Comment: 'code' ID NAME SKILL_TYPE ATTACK_TYPE DAMAGE_TYPE LAST_USED_DATE
1 Jiggle MANA MAGICAL WIND 2013-05-04T18:54:50.000Z
1 Jiggle MANA MAGICAL FIRE 2013-05-04T18:54:50.000Z
5 Bamboo Spikes MANA PHYSICAL PIERCING 2013-05-05T22:17:02.000Z
6 Burning Tail MANA PHYSICAL FIRE 2013-05-04T19:17:18.000Z
7 Haunt MANA MAGICAL DARK 2013-05-04T19:24:39.000Z
8 Rabid Bite MANA PHYSICAL DARK 2013-05-04T18:41:46.000Z 'code'

Comment: above 8 lines is my table data without any sorting, another idea i have is there any to set indexing to delete the dup rows automatically and then de-indexing it ?

Comment: one solution is I can insert auto increment primary key to do this

Comment: @KalpataruMallick See updated answer for a possible solution without having a PK on a table.

Answer (score 1):

Even without fiddle I give it a shot. Try this:

```
DELETE D1.* FROM DUMMY1 D1
JOIN (SELECT D.ID,D.NAME, MAX(LAST_USED_DATE) DATE FROM DUMMY1 D GROUP BY D.ID) D2 ON D1.ID = D2.D2
WHERE D1.NAME = D2.NAME AND D1.LAST_USED_DATE <> D2.DATE
```

I get the reverse since you are keeping the `MAX(LAST_USED_DATE)`

Comment: Unfortunately that query will delete all entries where id and name matches.